# How to login and get data using python request on a ASP.NET website?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a script which will login to a url and then get data from it. The web page is built using ASP.NET, The sample login page looks like this..

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderLogin_divLogin" class="NavNews" style="width: 300px; letter-spacing: normal; margin-top: 10px;
   font-size: 14px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
   <div style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
      <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderLogin_Login1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="width: 125px; float: left; text-align: right; padding-top: 3px;">User ID:</div>
               <div style="float: left; padding-left: 5px">
                  <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderLogin$Login1$UserName" type="text" value="test123" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderLogin_Login1_UserName" autocomplete="off" style="width:140px;"/>
               </div>
               <div style="width: 125px; float: left; text-align: right; padding-top: 3px;">Password:</div>
               <div style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                  <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderLogin$Login1$Password" type="password" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderLogin_Login1_Password" onkeypress="capLock(event)" autocomplete="off" style="width:140px;"/>
               </div>
               <br/>
               <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderLogin$Login1$Submit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderLogin_Login1_Submit" src="Images/submit.gif" style="border-width:0px;"/>
               <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderLogin_Login1_Clear" href="Login.aspx">
               <img src="Images/clear.gif" style="border-width:0px;"/>
               </a>
               <br/>
               <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderLogin_Login1_ForgotPWD" href="ForgotPassword.aspx" style="color:White;font-weight:bold;">Forgot Password?</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

So now i want to login and want to get data from the page after login. So I tried using request as follows;

```
LOGIN = 'https://www.leretanet.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx'
PROTECTED_PAGE = 'https://www.leretanet.com/Tax/TaxAmountReports.aspx?Menu=C#'
#requestUrl = 'https://www.leretanet.com/Tax/TaxAmountReports.aspx?Menu=C'

payload = {
        'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderLogin_Login1_UserName': 'test123',
        'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderLogin_Login1_Password': 'test123',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderLogin$Login1$Submit': 'submit'
        }

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'My user-agent'
    r = s.post(LOGIN, data=payload)
    response = s.get(PROTECTED_PAGE)
    print(response.text)
```

I expected to login and it would print the text of the page from the login.

However, the print(response.text) line simply prints the front page (not logged in). Like the login was not successful.

Comment: and what does happen instead?

Comment: add the parameter, `r = s.post(LOGIN, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)`, and try logging in.

Comment: That does change something: when I run the code I get a <Response [200]> code back. However, in the next line I try and run the following code: `response = s.get(PROTECTED_PAGE, verify=caPath, allow_redirects=True)` . Yet, it doesn't return the proper content I would expect from being logged in.